# spring mvc migrates to spring boot in spring mvc beans in xml and configruations also how to remove module dependancies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**spring mvc migrates to spring boot in spring mvc beans in xml and configruations also how to remove module dependancies? 
how spring mvc validator use in spring boot application?**

Comment: Please add more description to your post, Where you are facing issue ?

Comment: Hello Rishi, you can refer to a spring boot migration guide. For example this one [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration)

Comment: @Ajit Soaman           My old project is Spring Mvc I want Convert in Spring Boot Microservices.   so first part I want to convert that spring mvc to spring boot project. then I want to covertmicroservices. But all This spring mvc project version is 3.0v but all beans in xml format I don't want to touch in beans file beacause it's huge. All modules are dependent so how we convert?

Comment: @FarhanNayyer  Yes I have ues that site it's very use ful but all beans in xml format I don't want to touch in beans file beacause it's huge. All modules are dependent so how we convert? and I want to convert that project to microservice.

Comment: In Hibernate file they are use Composite-Id how to convert and use in java pojo class What is that Annotations.

Comment: @Rishi, If you still want to use XML with spring boot. then check for `ImportResource` annotation usage: @ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})